# String.size() won’t infinite loop

Tags: c++, size, infinite-loop

So I don’t know if it’s actually the size() function that’s causing this or not but whenever I run this code I expect it to infinitely loop but it does not. I’m using c++ and visual studio.

```
string name = “Devin”;
for(int i = 4; i < name.size(); i—-)
{
  printf(“%c”, name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that you are comparing signed and unsigned integers.

Comment: This code won't go infinite loop because it will result in compile error due to non-standard quotation marks and lack of semicolon.

Comment: `name.size()` returns an unsigned type.   When evaluating `i < name.size()`, `i` is promoted to that type.   When `i` becomes negative, the conversion does modulo arithmetic, so the result of converting `-1` to to an unsigned type is the maximum value that unsigned type can represent.  That value is never less than what `name.size()` can return, so the loop will stop when `i` reaches a value of `-1` (i.e.  the 6th iteration).

Comment: @Peter Your comment is not suitable as a comment. It should be an answer instead :)

Comment: @Peter thank you! That makes sense

Comment: Also note that you have a semicolon after the "for" declaration, so the printf line will execute only after the for (never if looping infinitely), not as the body of the for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your code like this:

```
string name = "Devin";
for(int i = 4; i < name.size(); i--)
    cout << name[i] << " i :" << i << "\n";
```

your output is:

```
n i: 4
i i: 3
v i: 2
e i: 1
D i: 0
```

Because
When comparing `signed` with `unsigned`, the compiler converts the `signed` value to `unsigned`. For equality, this doesn't matter, `-1 == (unsigned) -1`. For other comparisons it matters, e.g. the following is true: `-1 > 2U`.
`name.size()` is `unsigned` and `i` is going to `unsigned` number now and loop is end. For better understanding ; I used `5` instead of `name.size()` because `"Devin"` length is `5` .

```
for(int i = 4; i < 5; i--)
    cout<< name[i]<<" i: "<<i<<"\n";
```

And output is :

```
// Your i is going to negetive and infinity loop like 
i : -1 
i : -2
.
.
.
// and maybe you got segmentation fault (core dumped)
// Because your string just have 5 indexes
```

Comment: You need to explain why `Because name.size() is unsigned and -1 is a signed number .` causes the loop to stop. That's what the OP is confused about in the first place.

Comment: When comparing signed with unsigned, the compiler converts the ```signed``` value to ```unsigned```. For equality, this doesn't matter, ```-1 == (unsigned) -1```. For other comparisons it matters, e.g. the following is true: ```-1 > 2U```